# Printing off the content of Array or Set using for loop

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, set, println

When trying to print off the content of Set or Array using for loop I don't receive values but number of them. For example:

```
var favouriteSports: Set = ["Snowboarding", "Skateboarding", "Surfing"]
for genre in favouriteSports {
    print("\(genre)")
}
```

What I wanted to receive in console is "Snowboarding, Skateboarding, Surfing" but instead I receive "(3 times)"

I'm running the above code in "playground".
I just started with Swift, and I can't understand why such a simple thing is causing a problem.

Comment: where do you get it? in playground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a playground short styled screen. In your real project you will get the exact values. No problem. Also in a playground you can see the real values by clicking the "Show Result" button and then clicking the "All Values" button in the newly produced pane.

I've added a sample screen

[image]